# ProgressDialog appears too late

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Following is my code:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {


    dialog=new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setMessage("Initializing Please Wait");
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");

    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setProgress(0);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.show();
    progressStatus=0;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(progressStatus<10)
                {
                    progressStatus=performTask();


                }
                /*Dismiss the Progress bar*/
                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();//dismiss the dialog

                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       progressStatus=0;

                       myProgress=0;

                    }
                });

            }
            /* Do some task*/
            private int performTask()
            {
                try {
                    //---simulate doing some work---
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return ++myProgress;    
            }
        }).start();
}
```

Whenever I click the button, progressdialog appears after about 5seconds. I want my ProgressDialog to show up just after i click the button..Its emergency please Can anyone help please ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On my Nexus5 it appears instantly. With just few minor changes: `getBaseContext` ->`view.getContext`, `msg` ->`hello World`.

Answer (score 2):

*Do like the following* -

```
class RemoveAssignedVehicle extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Initializing Please Wait");
            pDialog.setTitle("Loading");
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressStatus=0;
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(progressStatus<10)
            {
                progressStatus=performTask();
            }

            return "";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),msg,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressStatus=0;

            myProgress=0;
        }
```

Comment: Is there any other way to make progress dialog appear fast?? without creating another class and just modifying the above code in the question

Comment: @user3631688 - This is the correct way to show the progress dialog. The way you are doing it in a thread is not the correct way and you should consider splitting your code between pre, background and post for the dialog to work as required.